# Problem with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete, plugins

I try to integrate the jQuery Autocomplete plugin [1], but doestn't work for me. Here my code:

```
$('#input').autocomplete(function(term) {
        var searchUrl = urlBase + 'tagging/autocomplete/?term=' + term;  
    $.getJSON(searchUrl, function(jsonData) {
        test = jsonData;
            console.log(test);
        });
    });
```

The output from console.log looks like:

```
[ "EBE", "EBE1", "EBE2"]
```

For the output i'm using the php function json_encode()

```
echo json_encode ($words);
```

Can someone tell me, what is wrong on my code? With the dummy data from the plugin page is working....but not when i try to retrive the data over the URI.

[1] http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are erroneously passing a function as the first parameter to `autocomplete`. The method signature is:

```
autocomplete( url or data, options );
```

and you're doing:

```
autocomplete(function(term) {
```

Instead of that, pass your url as the first parameter, and mod your server code to read the automatically appended 'q' parameter (which represents the *term* or string in the bound input element):

```
$('#input').autocomplete('tagging/autocomplete/', {
     formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
         return "<font color='#3399CC'>" + value + "</font>";
     },
     formatResult: function(data,value) {
         return value;
     }
}).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The manual says:

> For remote autocomplete, specify a URL
>   to the resource providing the data.
>   The plugin then requests data with a
>   "q" parameter containing the current
>   search value.

I've never tried to return json to an autocompleter (I'm sure you can) but the above assumes the data returned from the server is separated by a newline `"\n"` (autocomplete converts those into LIs).